# Is it somehow possible to create image files from GWT charts on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'd need to do an app that runs on google app engine that would be able to automatically create some image files from GWT graphics on server that would be later automatically attached in an email that would be automatically sent once a week.

But as far as I've investigated I see no possible way to do it on server, first off, I haven't been able to use ImageCharts on google appengine I had to use ColumnCharts and LineCharts, so that would complicate the process to turn then into images, althoug I think it could be done although it could take a while, although maybe it would be impossible to do it.

Biggest problem I see is that Google App Engine has File I/O absolutely banned, so although there might be a workaround, I guess it's a difficult one, I know about blobstore, but from what I've seen it just allows you to upload already existing files from you own PC, not to create new ones.

Is there something that could be done?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by ImageCharts,ColumnCharts and LineCharts

Comment: This is a Columnchart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart, this is a linechart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart and this is a imagechart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/genericimagechart. I wasn't able to use an Imagechart that has the advantage to already be an image on server, just locally, anyway as shown here: www.battlehorse.net/attach/topics/charts/google_charts_to_image.html it's likely it can be done, one way or another, biggest issue is to be able to create image file on server.